# Meaning of files under /etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d/?

Tags: 14.04, xubuntu, lightdm

I installed Xubuntu from an .iso image. Then I installed `ubuntu-desktop` package from the repositories and removed xubuntu.

However, the only file under `/etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d` is `10-xubuntu.conf`. Now that I have removed xubuntu and I am using ubuntu, shouldn't this file be gone? Shouldn't it be `10-ubuntu.conf` instead?

My question is:

What do the files under `/etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d/` do?
Is it safe for me to replace `10-xubuntu.conf` with `10-ubuntu.conf`?

Comment: The configuration files from Ubuntu-related things would be in `/usr/share/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d/`. I think it maybe a bug that `10-xubuntu.conf` is in `/etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d/`.

Comment: @muru So I can safely erase `10-xubuntu.conf` from `/etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d/`?

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong , but /etc stores only configuration files , and if you remove something only executable files/binaries are removed. So that may be reason why it wasn't deleted

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The contents of `10-xubuntu.conf` are:

```
[SeatDefaults]
user-session=xubuntu
```

In contrast, Ubuntu (that is to say, `ubuntu-desktop`) usually keeps configuration for LightDM in `/usr/share/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d`, where you should find a `50-ubuntu.conf`:

```
$ cat /usr/share/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d/50-ubuntu.conf 
[SeatDefaults]
user-session=ubuntu
```

If this files exists, and has the same contents, you can go ahead and uninstall `xubuntu-default-settings`, [the package that owns](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?searchon=contents&keywords=10-xubuntu.conf&mode=exactfilename&suite=trusty&arch=any) `10-xubuntu.conf`:

```
sudo apt-get purge xubuntu-default-settings
```

That would be cleaner than deleting or replacing `10-xubuntu.conf`.