# Revert XFCE Login Screen To Unity

Tags: unity, login, xfce

I have XFCE installed on 14.10 and I wanted to revert the login screen to the Unity one. I have KDE,LXDE,Unity and XFCE.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From this [slightly old question](https://askubuntu.com/q/537511/158442), the package [`xubuntu-default-settings`](http://packages.ubuntu.com/utopic/all/xubuntu-default-settings/filelist) sets the LightDM greeter to the Xubuntu one. In 14.10, it uses the file `/usr/share/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d/60-xubuntu.conf`. Either delete this file, or copy `/usr/share/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d/50-ubuntu.conf` to a higher number:

```
sudo cp /usr/share/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d/50-unity-greeter.conf /usr/share/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d/99-unity-greeter.conf
```

This will set the Unity greeter as the highest priority.

Comment: How do I copy it to a new number? Maybe I could run sudo apt-get remove xubuntu-default-settings and get rid of it.

Comment: @penguin2233 The command to copy is given. You could remove `xubuntu-defult-settings`, but it would remove other Xubuntu-related configuration. I'd think this is simpler.

Comment: @penguin2233 Ah, dammit. The command had the wrong source filename, sorry about that.

Comment: In fact I have installed LXDE,KDE,XFCE and Unity so it would be good to remove the settings

Comment: @penguin2233 Yes, I suppose in that case that might be simpler.